# Can't edit example sketch in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, edit

I am new to Arduino. I choose the example Blink and tried to change the times in the loop.
The file is readonly. Following the tutorials I try to save it in my sketchbook folder.

> File> Save as

is grayed out.
I copy the example folder from its location in Arduino/content/examples to my sketch book. Same result. No editing possible.
What is going wrong?
Arduino nano Every
Arduino 18.10
MacOS 10.14

Comment: did you check "Use external editor" in Preferences?

Comment: Just copy and paste the whole sketch into a new file.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

If you select Use External Editor, it will gray out the screen and prevent any typing.

> File | Preferences | Use External Editor

So just deselect this.

Have a look [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=93338.0)

Comment: That saved my day. I was using arduino IDE within Xcode with a template from embedXcode where external editor seems to be required. Thanks.